# Image Processing - Detection of joint features in volumetric wire-like shapes (fibres)

Tags: image, image-processing, alignment, volume, keypoint

I am dealing with some research on the analysis of fibres in Steel fibre reinforced concrete, and after a few months on an automatic research based on the analysis of the hessian matrix for each pixel, i find myself stuck.
The above mentioned analysis works, but it doesn't take into account that my fibres (that you can see in the pictures) have hooked parts in the end and those hooks ruin the whole analysis of the orientation tensor.

[image]

Now by using the information i'm extracting already pixel by pixel, i would like to try to identify the 6 points of interest for each fibre (that is beginning, end, and the 4 points in which it bends) to proceed then with a model matching.

I have a volumetric dataset describing the concrete volume and all the fibres inside, smoothed through a gaussian (each fibre is 400 pixel long and 8 pixel thick).

Do you have any idea or hint that could speed up my attempt to localize those feature keypoints that i could later use for some space-indexed model matching with a model of the fibre?